# Problem reading pdf file for azure form recognizer

Tags: azure, azure-form-recognizer

I am very new to using Azure. I am trying to extract data from a pdf using Azure Form Recognizer built-in model. For that, I have taken the code from the Microsoft documentation for python and trying to implement in jupyter notebook. The pdf is in my local computer in the same directory where my .ipynb file is. But the problem is this line of code is not executing. Is it the correct way of specifying the pdf file or am I doing something wrong. Please help. Thanks in advace :)

```
form_recognizer = client.begin_recognize_content_from_url("test_file.pdf")
```

Comment: How's going? Has your issue got resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
from azure.ai.formrecognizer import FormRecognizerClient
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential

form_recognizer_client = FormRecognizerClient(endpoint='<endpoint>', credential=AzureKeyCredential('<key>'))

filePath = "<file path>"

f = open(filePath,'rb').read()

result = form_recognizer_client.begin_recognize_content(f).result()
print(result)
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is not a URL, so remove `from_url` in `begin_recognize_content_from_url`:

```
form_recognizer = client.begin_recognize_content("test_file.pdf")
```